# How to fix this code so instead of having to hold button to change led, you can press?

Tags: led, button

```
const int buttonPin = 1; // the pin number of the pushbutton input pin
const int ledPins[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13};    // variables will change:
int buttonState = 0; // variable for reading the pushbutton status
int buttonPressCount = 0;
int numberOfLED = 8;

void setup() {    // initialize the LED pin as an output:
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLED; i++) {
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }    
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {    // read the state of the pushbutton value:
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);    // check if the pushbutton is pressed.    // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
  if (buttonState  == HIGH) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLED; i++) {
      if (buttonPressCount % numberOfLED == i)
        digitalWrite(ledPins[i], HIGH);  // turn LED on
      else
        digitalWrite(ledPins[i], LOW);   // turn LED off
    }
  }    
  buttonPressCount++;    
  delay(300);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of changing every time the buttonState == HIGH, change it when the button state was `LOW` the previous time but `HIGH` now:

```
buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
if (oldButtonState != buttonState && buttonState == HIGH) {
    //...
}
oldButtonState = buttonState;
```

However keep in mind contact bounce. Which can result in multiple transitions being detected. Most solutions for that set a minimal delay between handling transitions, dropping all others detected.